# Use user agent style

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to use user-agent styles no matter what?

for example I want the normal color behavior of anchor elements for a specific section.

CSS:

```
  .reset a {
    color: initial;
  }

  .reset a:visited {
      color: initial;
  }

  .reset a:link {
      color: initial;
  }

  .reset a:active {
      color: initial;
  }

  .reset a:visited {
      color: initial;
  }

  .reset a:hover {
      color: initial;
  }
```

don't work;

http://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/rjNWxZ

Comment: I will be having my own styles, but inside a `div` I want user agent styles for `anchor` tag. Say for a cleaner(?) look. Check my pen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You can't guarantee that there won't be an overriding rule that has a more specific selector and has `!important`.

You also need to specify the value explicitly. `initial` is not the same as the value from the UA stylesheet.

You could loop over all the elements with JS and set inline style on them, but again, some other code could interfere with your JS.

(NB: Your syntax is SCSS and not CSS).

Comment: Updated the code. How about in the simplest case? as in the codepen provided? Is there a way? What inline style should I set to get the user agent styles? Thanks.

Comment: @AsimKT — See the second paragraph. You can't get the UA styles. (Well, not without generating elements which aren't styled and then reading their computed styles … which wouldn't work for :visited because that is blocked for security reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
.section a, .section a:visited, .section a:link, .section a:active, .section  a:visited, .section a:hover {
   color: initial;
  }
```

Comment: er.. Sorry.. I was using less. Both styles are same. updated question

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

**HTML**

```
<section>
<a href="#">sample one</a>
  <div class="reset">
    <a href="#">two</a>
    <a href="#">three</a>
    <a href="#">four</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.section a, .section a:visited, .section a:link, .section a:active, .section  a:visited, .section a:hover {
   color: initial;
  }
```